# Deducting flat value and percentage in same function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to deduct a flat value, in this case, 0.35 as well as a percentage, in this case, 5.79 in one function.

My function as of now looks like this:

```
=I3-0.35*(1-5.79%)
```

Individually they both of them work. -0.35 would result in a cell reading 2.04. However, once I add the percentage deduction to the formula it reads 2.06 whereas the desired outcome should be ~1.92.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations

Comment: `=(I3-0.35)*(1-5.79%)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a parenthesis
The formula should be like:

```
=(I3-0.35)*(1-5.79%)
```